# chage page url using .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have two page in my root diectory i want to call those two page

In one anchor tag href i give path

```
<a href="companydetail.php?catid=<?php echo $cat1 ?>" >
```

when i do normal call then url like

```
mysite.com/companydetail.php?catid=category1
```

but when that page is call i want to show url like

```
mysite.com/category1
```

In second anchor tag href i give path

```
<a href="store.php?stid=<?php echo $str1 ?>" >
```

when i do normal call then url like

```
mysite.com/store.php?stid=store1
```

but when that page is call i want to show url like

```
mysite.com/store1
```

please give me answer as possible as 
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

this problem can be best solved with mod_rewrite.
the following link will show you exactly how to do it.

if you have any question, keep asking.

http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html

Answer (score 0):

Company Url

```
mysite.com/companydetail.php?catid=category1
```

can be converted to

```
mysite.com/company/category1
```

Use the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^/company/(.*)$ companydetail.php?catid=$1
```

Store URL

```
mysite.com/store.php?stid=store1
```

can be converted to

```
mysite.com/stores/store1
```

Use the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^/stores/(.*)$ store.php?stid=$1
```